# Problem with horizontal alignment in align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align, empheq

My MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{4}{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 10 ^{-6}}\right)^2 \; &? \; \left(\frac{1}{2 \cdot 10 ^{-6} \cdot 450 \cdot 10 ^{-12}}\right)\\\nonumber
1 \cdot 10 ^{12} \; &< \; 1{,}\overline{1} \cdot 10 ^{15}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

and displaying

[image]

**?** and **<** is not aligning. How is it changing macro in my MWE?

Answer (score 6):

Horizontal alignment in this case relies on the fact that the aligned symbols have the same width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\qrel}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\doqrel\relax}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doqrel}[2]{%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th#1?$\hidewidth\cr\hphantom{$\m@th#1=$}\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\left(\frac{4}{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 10 ^{-6}}\right)^{\!2}
  &\qrel \left(\frac{1}{2 \cdot 10 ^{-6} \cdot 450 \cdot 10 ^{-12}}\right)\\
1 \cdot 10 ^{12}
  &< 1{,}\overline{1} \cdot 10 ^{15}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need the “unknown relation” symbol just in text size (not in subscripts or superscripts) you can simplify the definition as

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\qrel}{\mathrel{%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th?$\hidewidth\cr\hphantom{$\m@th=$}\cr}%
}
\makeatother
```

Note that `empheq` is irrelevant here: the `align` environment is defined by `amsmath` (which is loaded by `empheq`, though).

Note also that the only spacing refinement is the `\!` in the exponent; adding `\;` in equation is something very rarely needed.

Answer (score 5):

You need to give the `?` the same spacing as the `<` by typing `\mathrel{?}`. Also you might want to leave out the extra `\;` on both sides, as TeX keeps track of correct spacing for relations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{4}{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 10 ^{-6}}\right)^2 &\mathrel{?} \left(\frac{1}{2 \cdot 10 ^{-6} \cdot 450 \cdot 10 ^{-12}}\right)\\\nonumber
1 \cdot 10 ^{12} &< 1{,}\overline{1} \cdot 10 ^{15}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

If you want to have it *exactly* in the middle of the `<`, then you should use the macro `\maybe` defined below. You use it like

```
\maybe[<relation>]
```

where `<relation>` is the the relations symbol (e.g. `=`, `<`, `>`, …) which width you want to mimic. The default relation is `=`, empty `[]` or of course `[?]` restore the default, but still with `\mathrel` around. `\maybe` also works properly in subscripts and superscripts (even though it should not be necessary).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\maybe[1][=]{
  \ifx\relax#1\relax
    \mathpalette\@maybe{?}
  \else
    \mathpalette\@maybe{#1}
  \fi
}
\newcommand*\@maybe[2]{
  \mathrel{\ooalign{$#1?$\cr\hidewidth$#1\hphantom{#2}$\hidewidth\cr}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$(a \maybe b)_{(a \maybe b)_{(a \maybe b)}}$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{4}{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 10 ^{-6}}\right)^2 &\maybe[<] \left(\frac{1}{2 \cdot 10 ^{-6} \cdot 450 \cdot 10 ^{-12}}\right)\\\nonumber
1 \cdot 10 ^{12} &< 1{,}\overline{1} \cdot 10 ^{15}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The red line is not produced by the MWE above.

> [image]

Comment: I'd add that those two symbols have different width and the alignment is on the left side of the symbols.

Comment: Suggestion: `\mathrel{\makebox[\widthof{$<$}]{?}}` with `calc` package in place.

Comment: @sigur, a little shift left.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, it is working.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This would insert the `?` from the current text font instead of the math font. You might want to use `\mathrel{\makebox[\widthof{$<$}]{$?$}}` instead.

Comment: @HenriMenke `?` should go first in `\ooalign`, so it will set the height of the symbol. Otherwise the symbol will end having the same height as `<` (which is wrong). Why not `\newcommand\maybe[1][?]{...}`? The test you do will be true only if you call `\maybe[]` which doesn't seem sensible.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the improvement. What does the additional `\m@th` in your answer do?

Comment: @HenriMenke It clears possible nonzero values of `\mathsurround`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a TABstack approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath,calc}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setstackgap{S}{6pt}
\alignShortunderstack{
\left(\dfrac{4}{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 10 ^{-6}}\right)^2 
\mathrel{\protect\makebox[\widthof{$<$}]{$?$}}&
\left(\dfrac{1}{2 \cdot 10 ^{-6} \cdot 450 \cdot 10 ^{-12}}\right)
\\
1 \cdot 10 ^{12} <& 1{,}\overline{1} \cdot 10 ^{15}
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it's straightforward to use an `array` environment, with the material in the first and third columns set in `\displaystyle`.

To change the amount of whitespace that's inserted around the `?` and `<` symbols, modify the parameter `\arraycolsep`; its default value in most (all?) document classes is `5pt`; in the code below I've set it to `2.5pt`. The reason I suggest `2.5pt`, rather than some even smaller value, is that I think it's important not to risk visually obliterating the small `?` symbol between the two large parenthetic groups. (For comparison, going the `align` route would insert `\thickmuskip`, which is about *40% less* whitespace.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2.5pt} % default value: 5pt
\begin{array}{ >{\displaystyle}r c >{\displaystyle}l }
\left(\frac{4}{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 10 ^{-6}}\right)^{\!2}
   &?& 
   \left(\frac{1}{2 \cdot 10 ^{-6} \cdot 450 \cdot 10 ^{-12}}\right)\\[3ex]
1 \cdot 10 ^{12} 
   &<& 
   1{,}\overline{1} \cdot 10 ^{15}\\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This inserts an "undesired" (maybe not for OP) `\arraycolsep` around the relations.

Comment: @HenriMenke - Thanks. I've modified the code to incorporate a reduction in the value of `\arraycolsep`.

Comment: Wrong. You should say `{@{}>{\displaystyle}r@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}>{\displaystyle}l@{}}`

Comment: @egreg - I don't agree. Given the massive visual presence of the large parentheses on either side of the puny little `?` symbol, inserting only `\thickmuskip` as the amount of whitespace on either side of the `?` and `=` symbols -- which is what the `@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}` construct delivers -- risks dwarfing the `?` symbol, visually speaking. That's why I suggest allocating a bit more whitespace around the central symbols. At any rate, the difference between `5mu` (your suggestion) and `5pt` (=2\arraycolsep`, my suggestion) is not exactly pronounced.

Comment: With the standard setting, I get that `\thickmuskip` is 2.77771pt, which is larger than your proposed value of 2.5pt

Comment: @egreg -- The amount of intercolumn whitespace in an `array` equals `2\arraycolsep`.