# Why the comma does not get aligned when using the align* environment?

Tags: align

Consider the following

```
\begin{align*}
  p &\equiv q\\
  p &,q
\end{align*}
```

My understanding is that `\equiv` and `,` should be aligned and they aren't.

Comment: equiv has relation spacing like = so thick  space either side, comma has punctuation spacing so no space on the left and thin space on the right

Comment: Very similar question [Problem with horizontal alignment in align environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223528/problem-with-horizontal-alignment-in-align-environment)

Comment: You could use `p &\mathrel{,}q` to give `,` the same spacing as `≡` but that'll look odd in its own way. What's the use case here? Why would you want to do this?